# How to activate jsonc in Tcllib on Mac?

Tags: json, tcl

There appears to be a [C implementation of the json package in Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/dir?ci=c02f41029b09f0db&name=modules/json/c). Unfortunately, on macOS Mojave, with [tcl installed via home-brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tcl-tk), it is not available. How would I go about enabling this C implementation of the JSON parser? Tcllib's source distribution doesn't seem to have a way to enable/disable it.

Answer (score 2):

The overall collection of accelerators for tcllib are built with the [critcl](http://andreas-kupries.github.io/critcl/) package. Alas, the tcl-tk recipe in Homebrew doesn't include the instructions for doing that (optional!) part of the build.

Alas, I don't know the exact set of instructions for getting everything enhanced with the runtime accelerators. Part of it is [making critcl work](https://andreas-kupries.github.io/critcl/doc/files/critcl_installer.html), and *theoretically* then you can just do `package require tcllibc` and it should build for you…

I advise contacting the [maintainer of tcllib and critcl](https://github.com/andreas-kupries) directly. He'll be able to advise (and the lack of even basic documentation on how to make tcllibc is IMO an [outright bug](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/tktview/f61f2e83a30d152d123474d9529f83e06c2bda9e)).

Answer (score 0):

Based on a hint from the [maintainer of tcllib and critcl](https://github.com/andreas-kupries), I managed to get it done this way (assuming you start from a source distribution of `tcllib`):

(1) Obtain and install `critcl`; I prefer the [source distribution](https://github.com/andreas-kupries/critcl/releases), after unpacking run from within the `critcl` source directory:

```
/path/to/homebrews/tclsh build.tcl install
```

(2) Obtain `tcllib`; I guess that you will have to start from the [source distribution](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/technote/) as well, I don't know whether the brewed install maintains what is needed for `tcllibc` to be built.

(3) Build and install `tcllibc` (from within the `tcllib` source directory);

```
make critcl
```

This assumes that `critcl` was installed in step (1) and that your PATH env variable covers the installation path of the `critcl` executable. In doubt, set the PATH explicitly:

```
PATH=/path/to/critcl/bin/dir:$PATH make critcl
```

(4) Install `tcllib` + `tcllibc` (from within `tcllib`'s src dir)

```
/path/to/homebrews/tclsh installer.tcl
```

(5) Verify the availability of `tcllibc`:

```
$ /path/to/homebrews/tclsh
% package req tcllibc
0.3.15
% package req json
1.3.4
% info commands ::json::many_json2dict_critcl 
::json::many_json2dict_critcl
```

The last `info` call establishes whether the C-based json implementation is available and loaded.

Comment: The installation steps will have to be run under `sudo`, just omitted for clarity.

Comment: I've done all of the above and while all of it succeeds, I do not end up with Tcllibc available. I can see tcllibc.dylib in the source directory but it is never installed. Is there a separate command I need to use to do this?

Comment: I appear to have found my answer: https://blog.tcl.tk/12099. It says "There is currently no provision to automate installation, so installing is a matter of copying the contents of modules/tcllibc to something like /lib/tcllibc." So, copying it is.